# JQuery hover out when cursor already over element on page load

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover, mouseout

I have an element which is visible on page load.

What happens in an ideal world is as follows:

If and when the cursor hovers over and then out of that element, the element fades out.

This works fine in this scenario, but if the cursor is already over the element on page load and the cursor is moved off the element very quickly, the hover out function does not always run - though it works fine if you hover out of the element more slowly.

```
$(".myElement").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).fadeIn(250);
  },
  function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(250); // This does not happen if cursor already over element on page load and mouse out very quickly
  }
);
```

The problem seems to be that when the cursor is moved of the element quickly, the page does not register that it was ever over the element in the first place.

Comment: Try using `stop` method.

Comment: @undefined - how would I use that?

Comment: There are many examples here! http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: try mouseEnter & mouseLeave

Answer (score 0):

use [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/);

try this

```
$(".myElement").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).stop(true, true).fadeIn(250);
  },
  function () {
     $(this).stop(true, true).fadeOut(250); // This does not happen if cursor already over element on page load and mouse out very quickly
```

}
);

Comment: No joy... The problem appears to be that when the cursor is moved off really quickly, it doesn't ever register as having been over the element.